# Geoserver sql view - parametric errors

Tags: geoserver

I can not get it to work. I started with complex sql and ended with 'hello word' example, but I get errors:
My sqls are:

- SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.coordinates, t.size, t.price FROM my_table t WHERE t.id=%id_param%
  Error: Failed to create SQL view: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 100
- SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.coordinates, t.size, t.price FROM my_table t WHERE t.id='%id_param%'
  Error: Failed to create SQL view: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" Position: 100

I am not sure, what I am missing.
I am using approx 2 months old OpenGeo suite (4.0.2).

> About GeoServer General information about GeoServer Build Information Version
>   2.4-SNAPSHOT Git Revision f295d37d70c3b1f0e51942e8b031253e4d75459 Build Date 20-Jan-2014 22:29 GeoTools Version 10-SNAPSHOT (rev
>   3bb3df4f410750baf9ebc48c9c475a70642aadb6) GeoWebCache Version
>   1.5.0 (rev 1.5.x/f981cafd349886bb2a1ef45067f26b1aa8e4aff4)

Answer (score 3):

Have you set a **Default value** for the id_param under the *SQL view parameters* section?  Try using your first query (without the quotes) and entering 0 for under the default value

Comment: OMG. Simple but obscure...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing the select syntax with "like" as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422455/performing-a-like-comparison-on-an-int-field)

Comment: LIKE for interger field?

Comment: you have never told us that "id_param" was a integer field. I edited my answer.

Comment: I though that is logic based on field name.

Comment: Does the syntax work in pgadmin or psql?

Comment: Yes it does work in pgadmin, but not geoserver.